# Dynamically construct insert statement

Tags: c#, sql, dynamic, insert

My insert statement looks as follows:

```
using (OleDbCommand cmd2 = conn2.CreateCommand())
{
    conn2.Open();
    cmd2.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Panel " + "([Symbol Name SE], [Symbol Name EP]) " + "VALUES(@Type01, @Type02)";
    cmd2.Parameters.AddRange(new OleDbParameter[]
    {
        new OleDbParameter("@Type01", variable1),
        new OleDbParameter("@Type02", variable2),
    });
    cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn2.Close();
}
```

I'd like to convert this into a generic insert function to which I can pass a table name, several columns and values, both as arrays and the function will construct the insert statement and execute it. I did try creating it with StringBuilder but I was not able to do it successfully. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What is your question? Or did you expect us to write all the code for you?

Comment: You may find some useful ideas here: https://samsaffron.com/archive/2012/01/16/that-annoying-insert-problem-getting-data-into-the-db-using-dapper

Comment: @PatrickHofman: I'd like some pointers on what to look into. So far I saw somewhat similar situations handled using StringBuilder, I'm not sure if it'll work in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it.

```
  public void dbQuery(string tablename, string[] columns, string[] values)
    {
        OleDbConnection conn2 = new OleDbConnection();
        using (OleDbCommand cmd2 = conn2.CreateCommand())
        {
            conn2.Open();
             StringBuilder build = new StringBuilder($"INSERT INTO {tablename} {string.Join(",",columns)}");

            foreach (string paramValue in values)
            {
                int count = 0;
                string paramName = $"@Type0{count.ToString()}";
                build.Append(paramName);
                 cmd2.Parameters.Add(
                 new OleDbParameter(paramName, paramValue.ToString()),
            );

                count++;
            }
            cmd2.CommandText = build.ToString();
            cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn2.Close();
        }
    }
```

Take care by yourself of string null/empty values.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest you go with a custom class that handles your Column/Value management, like so;

```
public class MyCustomColumn
{
    public string ColumnName {get; set;}
    public object Value {get; set;}
}
```

This way you can pass in an array;

```
CreateGenericInsertFunction(string tableName, MyCustomColumn[] columns)
```

You could just as easily use a `KeyValuePair` or a `Tuple` but the custom class gives you more flexibility in terms of extensibility.

Then you can do something like;

```
string colList = "";
string valList = "";
foreach (var col in columns)
{
    if (colList.length == 0)
    {
        colList += ", " + col.ColumnName;
    }
    else
    {
        colList += col.ColumnName;
    }

    // repeat for Value
}
// Finally, join it all together.
```

Comment: Looks good. However, I'm a bit confused as to what the purpose of get and set are, inside the MyCustomColumn class. Could you explain?

Comment: Doesn't look good. This code is very dangerous. Read up on SQL injection attacks.